# array's initialization body as function parameter (C-array), is it possible?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, initialization

I am searching for some help in next situation:
I have some class and some method in it, syntax is like this:

```
class SomeClass {  
    public:  
            void doSomething(int *a);  
};
```

So I want to call this method like

```
SomeClass::doSomething({ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

Is it possible in any language?
Any (C++, C, obj-c, obj-c++) implementation is welcome! 
I know that this initialization block is a body of array, like

```
int *a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
SomeClass::doSomething(a);
```

But interface will look great, I think, if there will be no temp variables before function calls (as we don't need to know the type of parameter in class-client).  So, is there any chance to make this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is about C++11 [initializer lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists) (section [18.9](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)).

```
void foo (std :: initializer_list <int> inputs) {
    for (auto i : inputs) {
        // ...
    }
}

foo ({10, 20, 30});
```

Only the compiler can create an initializer list, but you can treat it like a standard STL-style container with `begin()`, `end()`, `size()`, and random-access iterators.

`std::vector` (and I expect some other containers) can now be constructed with initializer lists, so

```
std :: vector <std :: string> foo {"a", "b"};
```

is equivalent to

```
std :: vector <std :: string> foo;
foo .push_back ("a");
foo .push_back ("b");
```

except that it may perform fewer allocations. Note that the `const char*` have been turned into `std::string` automagically.

Comment: Actually, this will work with *any* container class, thanks to C++11's uniform initialization.

Answer (score 33):

In C99 this works:

```
functionThatTakesIntPtrOrArray( (int []){ 1, 2, 3, 4 } );
```

..and similar things can be done with structs.

Comment: Sadly doesn't work in C++. You get the error "taking address of temporary array".

Comment: Works with clang 6.0 (cpp)

Comment: I have been using this technique in Xcode with clang, and recently tried to compile it in visual studio 2017 without any success. I was wondering if this has any name, and why VS does not support it?

Answer (score 2):

If `initializer_list` is not available, and the arrays are mostly small, there is another option, overloading `<<` operator for std::vector like this:

```
template <typename T>
inline std::vector<T> operator <<( const std::vector<T>& vec, const T& val ) {
    std::vector<T> result(vec);
    result.push_back(val);
    return result;
}
```

With that, you can do this:

```
void foo (const std::vector<int>& inputs) {
    // ...
}

foo ( std::vector<int>() << 10 << 20 << 30 );
```

There is a price to pay for this convenience of single line initialization and not having to specify vector size. A copy of the prior vector is created for every element that is added, making running time at least quadratic in vector size -- that's why this is best suited for short vectors and cases when performance does not matter. There is a better solution for C++11, as pointed out in spraff's answer.

Answer (score 0):

one can initialize a temporary array as a function parameter like so

```
// onboard LED
const byte LED_RED = 36;
const byte LED_BLUE = 34;
const byte LED_GREEN = 35;
    
void turnOffLedAll(){
        // TURN OFF ALL LED
      digitalWrite(LED_RED, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED_BLUE, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED_GREEN, LOW);
    }
    
void statusLED(byte led[], byte stat, byte time=0) {
      turnOffLedAll();
      // turn ON LED
      for(int i=0; i<(sizeof(led)/sizeof(led[0])); i++){
        digitalWrite(led[i], stat);
      }
      if (time>0){
        delay(time*1000);
        turnOffLedAll();
      }
    }
```

Considering the functions above an inline array initialization as a function parameter can be done like this:

```
   statusLED((byte*)(const byte[]){LED_RED}, LOW, 0);
```