# How to create a constructor that accepts 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, constructor

Im creating my own matrix library for education purposes.
I created a constructor that accepts a 4x4 matrix in the form of

```
Matrix(float initMatrix[4][4]){
 //init operation here
}
```

The above constructor works fine when creating the object by creating a 2D array and then using that variable to initialize this object, for example:

```
float my_matrix[4][4] = {{...},{...},{...},{...}}; //shortened for brevity
Matrix matrix(my_matrix);
```

However, it fails to build when doing the following:

```
Matrix matrix({{...},{...},{...},{...}});
```

The compiler tells me

```
> cannot convert initializer list argument to 'float (*)[4]'
```

So I added another constructor that looks like this:

```
Matrix matrix(float matrix(*)[4]){}
```

I end up getting the following compiler error.

```
error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    Vytrix(float input(*)[4]){
```

Can someone show me a good flexible way of designing the constructors so that I can initialize the class in a clean way?

Comment: Try to initiallize using float lists `Matrix matrix(new float[4][4]{{...},{...},{...},{...}});`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16455029/2602718

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657910/arrays-initialization-body-as-function-parameter-c-array-is-it-possible and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537349/initialiser-list-passed-as-function-parameter-for-array and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force the dimensions you can accept a const reference to an array instead of passing the array directly:

```
struct Matrix {
    Matrix(const float (&initMatrix) [4][4]) {}
};

int main()
{
    Matrix m({{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}});
    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/ByzOQTkrQ

This is a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17569578/2193968

Answer (score 2):

You're using C++, so you can use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)!

`std::array` is [a little wonky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8192275/2602718) with initialization, so you'll need an extra set of curly braces. Here's a working example:

```
#include <array>

class foo
{
public:
    foo(std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 3> arr) { }
};

int main()
{
    foo f({{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}});
}
```

Comment: Isn't that bug long fixed by now?

Comment: @o11c [ideone](https://ideone.com/DmR8PD) still yells at me if I don't have the extra set of braces, so I figured I'd throw them in.

Comment: @scohe001 Thank you. I'll keep your answer in mind, for this particular project, I decided to go a bit bare-bones.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax would be:

```
Matrix(const float (&m)[4][4]);
```

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @L.Kue: That would solve OP's issue, so it is an answer. You might consider it as too short answer. Comments are mostly to ask "clarification"s.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you for your response, it works well!  Does this work because I am essentially passing a pointer by declaring it like this: Matrix matrix({{......}})?

Comment: @KhalidAkash: C-Arrays cannot be passed by value, so you have to pass them by pointer/reference. `Matrix(float initMatrix[4][4])` is in fact `Matrix(float (*initMatrix)[4])`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
struct Matrix
{
    float initMatrix[4][4];
};

int main()
{
    Matrix m{ { { 1,2,3,4 },{ 5,6,7,8 },{ 9,10,11,12 },{ 13,14,15,16 } } };
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/WeZjbY